# Service does not stop when app is closed by user

Tags: java, android, android-service, alarmmanager

So I'm attempting to make an alarmManager run every 60 seconds which will be running a http request to a server. I want the Service to run while the app is open and still run if the screen is off (sleep).

If the user swipes the app away under the recent apps menu, i want the service to stop/cancel.

The `Service.onDestroy` method only runs half the time it seems and the `Alarm.onReceive` method will run forever (every 60 seconds) even if app is closed.

calling `Alarm.cancelAlarm` makes no changes.

What am I missing?

AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".objects.Alarm"></receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".objects.Service"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":your_service"
        android:stopWithTask="true">
    </service>
```

Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    startService(new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, Service.class));
}
```

Service:

```
public class Service extends android.app.Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        alarm.setAlarm(this);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        alarm.cancelAlarm(this);
    }
}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("mytag","trigger update");
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000, pi);
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, myIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a receiver,service that is running on a separate thread.  remove the android:process="XX" and use START_STICKY.

It would be simpler if you used a JobService instead of a Service / Receiver combination for this.

**Try something like this:**

```
<service android:name=".services.AlarmService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

--

```
AlarmService.schedule(this,XXXX);
```

--

```
public class AlarmService extends JobService {

  private static String TAG = "AlarmService";

  public static void schedule(Context context, int minutes) {
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
        .setService(SubscriptionAlarmService.class) // the JobService that will be called
        .setTag(TAG)        // uniquely identifies the job
        .setRecurring(true)
        .setReplaceCurrent(true)
        .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(minutes * 60,(minutes * 60) + 10))
        .setLifetime(Lifetime.UNTIL_NEXT_BOOT)
        .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
        .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
        .build();
    dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
  }

  public static void CancelAlarm(Context context) {
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
    dispatcher.cancel(TAG);
  }

  public void run() {
    //DO STUFF HERE
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
    run();
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think FirebaseJobDispatcher is any good for me because on Android 24+ ScheduledJobs cannot be executed while the device is in doze mode, which can be a delay of 15 minutes, I need max of 2 minutes. Removing android:process="XX" did not stop the process either, but I think I've found an answer which I'm going to post now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `START_STICKY` instead `START_NOT_STICKY`

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way to do this but after testing it seems to work for me.

When the app is closed `onStartCommand` runs again and restarts the service, but intent is `null` so i just cancel the alarm if intent is `null`.

In my Service class:

```
   @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent == null) {
            alarm.cancelAlarm(this);
        } else {
            alarm.setAlarm(this);
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```